# Как скрыть кнопку от всех, кроме пользователя у которого

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Как скрыть кнопку от всех, кроме пользователя, который находится в таблице `users` и имеет e-mail: *igor@gmail.com*
Возможно такое реализовать?
К примеру, такая кнопка:

```
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Profile" class="special"/>
```

Comment: Это кнопка формы входа на сайт? И вообще какая задача?

Comment: да. это вполне типичная задача.

Answer (score 0):

Смотря как и где вы это реализовываете. Если к вам приходит пользователь у которого вы знаете его email и храните его например в переменной $email (PHP) то,

```
<?php if('igor@gmail.com' === $email) { ?>
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Profile" class="special"/>
<?php } ?>
```

Если нужно по другим данным сначала узнать его email в таблице users, то делаете это. Например:

```
SELECT email FROM users WHERE phone = '0990090909' [LIMIT 1]
```

Если данные о человека приходят из js, то получите их из $_GET/$_POST